# What is the proper setup for HAProxy with Openshift Custom Cartridges?

Tags: bash, openshift, haproxy

It seems as if many developers trying to move from non-scaled apps (like the diy cartridge) to scaled versions of their apps are having trouble configuring their cartridges to interact properly with the default configuration of HAProxy created by Openshift and getting their start and stop action hooks to deal with scaling portions of their app, myself included. Most often because we're new and we don't quite understand what the default configuration of openshift's HAProxy does...

### HAProxy's default configuration

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
# to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
# need to:
#
# 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
#    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
#    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
#
# 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
#   file. A line like the following can be added to
#   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
#
#    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
#
#log         127.0.0.1 local2

maxconn     256

# turn on stats unix socket
stats socket /var/lib/openshift/{app's ssh username}/haproxy//run/stats level admin

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    #option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 128

listen stats 127.2.31.131:8080
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /

listen express 127.2.31.130:8080

    cookie GEAR insert indirect nocache
    option httpchk GET /

    balance leastconn
    server local-gear 127.2.31.129:8080 check fall 2 rise 3 inter 2000 cookie local-{app's ssh username}
```

Often it seems like both sides of the application are up and running but HAProxy isn't sending http requests to where we'd expect. And from numerous questions asked on openshift we know that this line:

```
option httpchk GET /
```

Is HAProxy's sanity check to make sure the app is working, but often times whether that line is edited or removed we'll still get something like this in HAProxy's logs:

```
[WARNING] 240/150442 (404099) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4     connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup  servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 240/150442 (404099) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
```

Yet inside the gears we often have our apps listening to `$OPENSHIFT_CARTNAME_IP` and `$OPENSHIFT_CARTNAME_PORT` and we'll see they've started, and sometimes are rejecting the sanity check.

```
ERROR   [DST 127.2.31.129 sid=1] SHOUTcast 1 client connection rejected. Stream not available as there is no source connected. Agent: `'
```

### A cut and dry manifest, like the one from the diy cartridge

```
Name: hws
Cartridge-Short-Name: HWS
Display-Name: Hello World of Scaling Apps
Description: A Scaling App on Openshift
Version: '0.1'
License: ASL 2.0
License-Url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Cartridge-Version: 0.0.10
Compatible-Versions:
- 0.0.10
Cartridge-Vendor: you
Vendor: you
Categories:
- web_framework
- experimental
Website: 
Help-Topics:
  Getting Started: urltosomeinfo
Provides:
- hws-0.1
- hws
Publishes: 
Subscribes:
  set-env:
    Type: ENV:*
    Required: false
Scaling:
  Min: 1
  Max: -1
Group-Overrides:
- components:
  - web-proxy
Endpoints:
- Private-IP-Name: IP
  Private-Port-Name: PORT
  Private-Port: 8080
  Public-Port-Name: PROXY_PORT
  Protocols:
  - http
  - ws
  Options:
    primary: true
  Mappings:
  - Frontend: ''
    Backend: ''
    Options:
      websocket: true
  - Frontend: "/health"
    Backend: ''
    Options:
      health: true
```

### Start Hook (inside bin/control or in .openshift/action_hooks)

```
RESPONSE=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' "http://${OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS}:80")
${RESPONSE} > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/checkserver.log
echo ${RESPONSE}
if [ "${RESPONSE}" -eq "503" ]
then
    nohup ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/diy/serverexec ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/diy/startfromscratch.conf > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/server.log 2>&1 &
else
    nohup ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/diy/serverexec ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/diy/secondorfollowinggear.conf > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/server.log 2>&1 &
fi
```

### Stop Hook (inside bin/control or in .openshift/action_hooks)

```
kill `ps -ef | grep serverexec | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'` > /dev/null 2>&1
exit 0
```

## The helpful questions for new developers:

### Avoiding a killer sanity check

Is there a way of configuring the app using the manifest.yml to avoid these collisions? Or vice/versa a little tweak to the default HAProxy configuration so that the app will run on appname-appdomain.rhcloud.com:80/ without returning 503 errors?

### Setting up more convenient access to the app

*My shoutcast example, as hinted by the error works so long as I'm streaming to it first.* What additional parts to the manifest and HAProxy would let a user connect directly (from an external url) to the *first* gear's port 80? As opposed to port-forwarding into the app all the time.

### Making sure the app starts and stops as if it weren't scaled

Lastly many non-scaled applications have a quick and easy script to start up and shutdown because it seems openshift accounts for the fact the app has to have the first gear running. How would a stop action hook be adjusted to run through and stop all the gears? What would have to be added to the start action hook to get the first gear back up online with all of it's components (not just HAProxy)?